# How can i scrape all date with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I need to scrape soccerway.com and i have problem when i select date for example 2011-2013 going in every link of the match but the problem is saved only the last date 2012-2013 not 2011-2012 and 2012-2013 but only the last date.

```
from time import sleep
from urllib.parse import urlparse

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


def get_urls_season(url_path):

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.fullscreen_window()
    driver.get("https://us.soccerway.com" + url_path)
    click_privacy_policy(driver)
    date = date_selector(driver)
        #url_list = cycle_through_game_weeks(driver)
    url_list.reverse()
    driver.quit()

    print("=" * 100)
    print(f"{len(set(url_list))} find")

    if input("con? (y/n): ") != "y":
        exit()

    return url_list




def date_selector(driver):
    inptdate='2010-2012'
    startdate=inptdate.split('-')[0]
    enddate=inptdate.split('-')[1]

    while int(startdate)< int(enddate):
        textstring=str(startdate) + "/" + str(int(startdate)+1)
        print(textstring)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='season_id']/option[text()='" + textstring +"']").click()
        startdate=int(startdate)+1
        url_list = cycle_through_game_weeks(driver)

def click_privacy_policy(driver):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("qc-cmp-button").click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        pass


def cycle_through_game_weeks(driver):
    season_urls = get_fixture_urls(innerhtml_soup(driver))

    while is_previous_button_enabled(driver):
        click_previous_button(driver)
        sleep(2)

        urls = get_fixture_urls(innerhtml_soup(driver))


        urls.reverse()
        season_urls += urls

    return season_urls


def is_previous_button_enabled(driver):
    return driver.find_element_by_id(
        "page_competition_1_block_competition_matches_summary_5_previous"
    ).get_attribute("class") != "previous disabled"


def click_previous_button(driver):
    driver.find_element_by_id(
        "page_competition_1_block_competition_matches_summary_5_previous"
    ).click()


def get_fixture_urls(soup):

    urls = []
    for elem in soup.select(".info-button.button > a"):
        urls.append(urlparse(elem.get("href")).path)
    return urls


def innerhtml_soup(driver):

    html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("html").get_attribute("innerHTML")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    return soup
```

I need to scrape all date 2011-2013 
2011-2012 2012-2013 not only the last date 
And i can't find the problem why.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the code correctly, problem lies here:

```
url_list = cycle_through_game_weeks(driver)
```

in every iteration you are overriding old url_list with new one, simplest solution will be:

```
url_list += cycle_through_game_weeks(driver)
```

more elegant and effective:

```
   url_list = []
   while int(startdate)< int(enddate):
        textstring=str(startdate) + "/" + str(int(startdate)+1)
        print(textstring)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@name='season_id']/option[text()='" + textstring +"']").click()
        startdate=int(startdate)+1
        url_list.append(cycle_through_game_weeks(driver))
   return url_list
```

this way under url_list[0] you will get values from first year, under url_list[1] second and so on

Comment: I run the progam with second solution but i have error how can i solve                                                                                               
                                                                                                                             
 print(f"{len(set(url_list))} find")
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

Comment: these dots means that other parts remains unchaged